# binance API connection issue on linux error APIError(code=-2015)

Tags: binance

This is very puzzling to me but I am sure there is a simple explanation still as I exhausted all the reasonable ones that I can think off.

I have a python Binance trading script. I have my home public IP setup as a trusted IP. On my test macbook everything works great, however, on my linux server using the same ISP I get

```
APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action
```

I triple checked public IPs for both computers and, as expected, they are the same. When I switch to "unrestricted access" all works well, so it has something to do with IP restriction.

What am I missing? Binance help said they do not support API questions. Thank you.
Happy new year!

I toggled between restricted and unrestricted access, and it has something to do with the public IP. Also made sure all the packaged are same version, but there is a linux vs mac issue that I cannot resolve.

Answer (score 0):

We also had this from yesterday: The solution was to create a new API key with the same permissions (also IP restricted).

Comment: Great idea. Just tried that, but as soon as I restrict the IP, stops working.

Comment: I found it. After a linux upgrade my IPV6 was enabled.